# Message box ok cancel, how to cancel the event when user chooses Cancel option

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

This must be a really dumb question to you guys.

I was trying to add a message box in my win form, here is my code.

```
var result = MessageBox.Show(" date range over 16 days. Do you want to continue?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);

if(result == DialogResult.OK)
{

}
if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    //when its cancel i prefer to stay on the same window 
}
```

When I click ok button it continues, but I have no idea how to return to the same window if cancel button is clicked. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it will stay in the same form, if you don't have a command for closing the existing form when the messagebox is open?

Comment: i thought so but apparently it keep continue the next step when cancel called.

Answer (score 0):

The `MessageBox` in itself will not redirect on its own to anywhere else, it will just return control to the calling code without focusing another form or opening/closing anything. You have to explicitly write code for that to happen.

So, my guesses would be, and where I would start looking for something rare:

- The cancel handler contains some code that redirects the focus/closes/opens something else, anything different from the OK case
- Previous code to the call changes something that it should not do before checking the result.
- Anything external is "stealing" the focus or closing the window, like a timer or anything running in the background.

To be more helpful, what is your code in the cancel's `if`?

Comment: MessageBox.Show("The calculations are complete", "My Application",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

Comment: after this msg box i do call the webservice,if the ok event raised,if the cancel event raised it shouldn't move to next step but it does call my service too

Comment: Maybe it's a dumb thing, but are you by any chance reusing the `result` variable for the further messages? Now I'm thinking that it might happen that it enter both `if` blocks if you happen to change the value afterwards in the uppermost block.